# How To Find The Sum By Sum Of Alias Column Value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, sql-server-2017

Here i am trying to calculate the `SUM` of amount paid for Tution by particaular student in particular fiscal year and also for every month of that fiscal year.
For example in below line `PaidTutionFee` is calculated by `SUM(Tution) AS PaidTutionFee`. Now what i want is to sum `PaidTutionFee` column,

```
StudentId   FYID    Month   PaidTutionFee
7           16      3       2855.00
7           16      4       2855.00
```

For this i have sum the Tution i.e `SUM(Tution) AS PaidTutionFee`and group by `StudentId, FYId, Month` which will give the sum of Tution for every months for that fiscal year and finally to total Tution paid for entire fiscal year i  have sum the alias of `SUM(Tution) AS PaidTutionFee` i.e `SUM(PaidTutionFee) AS TotalTutionFeeInFiscalYear`.
Now the problem is that i throws an error saying

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'PaidTutionFee'.
```

Below is my sql server query

```
SELECT StudentId,FYId, Month, SUM(Tution) AS PaidTutionFee, 
SUM(PaidTutionFee) AS TotalTutionFeeInFiscalYear
FROM [dbo].[FeePaymentDetails]
WHERE FYId = 16 AND StudentId = 7 
GROUP BY StudentId, FYId, Month
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't aggregate an aggregate in the same SELECT statement. BUT... that's not really what you are after here. You want a sum of `tuition` when grouped by `StudentID, FYid, Month` AND a sum of `tuition` when grouped by `StudentID, FYid` (If I'm reading this correctly). For this you can use Window Functions:

```
SELECT StudentId,FYId, Month, SUM(Tution) AS PaidTutionFee
Sum(Tution) OVER (PARTITION BY SutdentID, FyID) as TotalTutionFeeInFiscalYear
FROM [dbo].[FeePaymentDetails]
WHERE FYId = 16 AND StudentId = 7 
GROUP BY StudentId, FYId, Month;
```

Now your result set's granularity is at the `StudentId, FYId, Month` level, but you have one extra column that has it's values repeated for every distinct `StudentId, FYId` and it's value represents the sum for that higher level of granularity that you are after.

Comment: You sure can aggregate an aggregate in the same query - check what a GROUPING SET / GROUP BY CUBE / GROUP WITH ROLLUP is. For my money I'd just use rollup for this one and accept the total the student pays as a freebie bonus data line

Comment: @CaiusJard That's a good call. I guess the "You can't aggregate an aggregate" isn't the right way to say it. You can't Sum(Sum(yourfield)). You can however toss a window function at it (as I did here) or `GROUP BY ROLLUP` which you did and I am upvoting as that is a 100% solid solution.

Answer (score 1):

The much under appreciated rollup and grouping sets facilities of sqlserver can do this one quite easily:

```
SELECT StudentId,FYId, Month, SUM(Tution) AS PaidTutionFee
Sum(Tution) OVER (PARTITION BY SutdentID, FyID) as TotalTutionFeeInFiscalYear
FROM [dbo].[FeePaymentDetails]
/*WHERE FYId = 16 AND StudentId = 7*/ 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(StudentId, FYId, Month)
```

I've picked ROLLUP because i think it's easiest to understand

Sqlserver will do your grouping as you ask, down to the month level so you'll get a row for every month. Then thanks to the addition of ROLLUP you'll get a row with a NULL month and that is the sum of everything for the student/year. You'll also get a row with null month and null year that is the sum for the student, and a row of all nulls that is the grand total for all students. The effect is thus that the grouping/summing "rolls up" from most precise (student/year/month) to least precise (one sum of everything) in the order of right-to-left depending on the order of columns in the group by

I commented out your where clause to better demo the rollup effect - if you put it back in you'll get some totals lines that are no different to what you already know (because there is only one student and one year, so the total for all students will be the same as the total for the one student etc)

GROUPING SETS let you fine tune the subtotal/grandtotal effect better

If you made your group by like this:

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((StudentId,FyId,Month),(StudentId,FyId))
```

You'll just get the month details (thanks to the first grouping set) and the lines where month is null (th total for the year) thanks to the second grouping set

Answer (score 0):

You can use over Partition By to calculate running totals and grand totals without need of group by:

```
SELECT StudentId,FYId, Month, SUM(Tuition) over (partition by StudentId, FyId) AS PaidTutionFee, 
SUM(Tution) over (partition by StudentId, Year(FyId)) AS TotalTutionFeeInFiscalYear
FROM [dbo].[FeePaymentDetails]
WHERE FYId = 16 AND StudentId = 7 
Order BY StudentId, FYId, Month
```